# How do I disable weekends and specific dates in this code for date picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using a plugin on woocommerce and I need to disable sundays and some specific dates (Xmas holidays) on date picker. Your help is much appreciated.
I have managed to disable the today date but I am struggling to do the rest.

Also is there a way of adding a if statement that if time is > 17:00 automatically datepicker changes to +2 days and else just +1?

```
(function( $ ) {  $(function() {
   if ($('.pcfme-datepicker').length) {
     $('.pcfme-datepicker').datepicker({
       dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy'
   });
   }
   var dateToday = new Date(); 
  dateToday.setDate(dateToday.getDate() + 1);
   if ($('.pcfme-datepicker-disable-past').length) {
     $('.pcfme-datepicker-disable-past').datepicker({
       dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
       minDate: dateToday
   });
   }

});
```

Comment: Hey man, how do you read this code? My advice is to spend time cleaning up your code by keeping it DRY. Because not everyone has experience with WOOCOMMERCE, it'll help the rest of the community if you shared code that is easy to read and follow.

Comment: Hi Rich, 
Just done that

Comment: Am I correct to assume that you're "disabling" dates by assigning a CSS class to a given date?

Comment: Is that part of the plugin you're using?

Comment: Hi Rich, It is part of a plugin but just this bit of code changes the actual frontend appearance of date picker.

Comment: Also this bit of code is being used to disable current day but i am not using any css
 var dateToday = new Date(); 
  dateToday.setDate(dateToday.getDate() + 1);